# pandas: finding maximum for each series in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,size=(5, 4)),
              columns=list('ABCD'),
              index=pd.date_range('2016-04-01', '2016-04-05'))

date       A   B   C   D
1/1/2016  15   5  19   2
2/1/2016  18   1  14  11
3/1/2016  10  16   8   8
4/1/2016   7  17  17  18
5/1/2016  10  15  18  18
```

where `date` is the index

what I want to get back is a tuple of `(date, <max>, <series_name>)` for each column:

```
   2/1/2016, 18, 'A'
   4/1/2016, 17, 'B'
   1/1/2016, 19, 'C'
   4/1/2016, 18, 'D'
```

How can this be done in idiomatic pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Setup

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(314)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,size=(5, 4)),
                  columns=list('ABCD'),
                  index=pd.date_range('2016-04-01', '2016-04-05'))

print df

             A   B   C   D
2016-04-01   8  13   9  19
2016-04-02  10  14  16   7
2016-04-03   2   7  16   3
2016-04-04  12   7   4   0
2016-04-05   4  13   8  16
```

#### Solution

```
stacked = df.stack()
stacked = stacked[stacked.groupby(level=1).idxmax()]
```

#### produces

```
print stacked

2016-04-04  A    12
2016-04-02  B    14
            C    16
2016-04-01  D    19
dtype: int32
```

Comment: This is beautiful.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) and [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html). Last you can [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) column `index` and reorder all columns:

```
print df
           A   B   C   D
date                    
1/1/2016  15   5  19   2
2/1/2016  18   1  14  11
3/1/2016  10  16   8   8
4/1/2016   7  17  17  18
5/1/2016  10  15  18  18

print pd.concat([df.max(),df.idxmax()], axis=1, keys=['max','date'])
   max      date
A   18  2/1/2016
B   17  4/1/2016
C   19  1/1/2016
D   18  4/1/2016

df = pd.concat([df.max(),df.idxmax()], axis=1, keys=['max','date'])
       .reset_index()
       .rename(columns={'index':'name'})
#change order of columns
df = df[['date','max','name']]
print df
       date  max name
0  2/1/2016   18    A
1  4/1/2016   17    B
2  1/1/2016   19    C
3  4/1/2016   18    D
```

Another solution with [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
print pd.concat([df.max().rename_axis('name'), df.idxmax()], axis=1, keys=['max','date'])
      max      date
name               
A      18  2/1/2016
B      17  4/1/2016
C      19  1/1/2016
D      18  4/1/2016

df = pd.concat([df.max().rename_axis('name'), df.idxmax()], axis=1, keys=['max','date'])
       .reset_index()
#change order of columns
df = df[['date','max','name']]
print df
       date  max name
0  2/1/2016   18    A
1  4/1/2016   17    B
2  1/1/2016   19    C
3  4/1/2016   18    D
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) and [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) with axis=0 for that and then join them:

```
np.random.seed(632)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,size=(5, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

In [28]: df
Out[28]:
    A   B   C   D
0  10  14  16   1
1  12  13   8   8
2   8  16  11   1
3   8   1  17  12
4   4   2   1   7

In [29]: df.idxmax(axis=0)
Out[29]:
A    1
B    2
C    3
D    3
dtype: int64

In [30]: df.max(axis=0)
Out[30]:
A    12
B    16
C    17
D    12
dtype: int32


In [32]: pd.concat([df.idxmax(axis=0) , df.max(axis=0)], axis=1)
Out[32]:
   0   1
A  1  12
B  2  16
C  3  17
D  3  12
```